# how to get the column name from multiple column into one if its true in pyhton?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a data frame

```
A     B      C    
True  False  False
False False  True
True  False  False
False False  False
```

I want to get column named "result" which will return the column name if it is true and nan, if any of it is not True.

Expected Column

```
result
A
C
A  
na
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to set the column value to either the [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) along the second axis, so the respective column name of the first `True`, or `NaN`, depending on the result of `df.any(1)` :

```
df['result'] = df.idxmax(1).where(df.any(1))
```

Or for a `numpy` based one you can use `argmax` instead:

```
import numpy as np

df['result'] = np.where(df.values.any(1), df.columns[df.values.argmax(1)], np.nan)
```

---

```
print(df)

       A      B      C result
0   True  False  False      A
1  False  False   True      C
2   True  False  False      A
3  False  False  False    NaN
```

Comment: **My problem is that I have a large dataset with near about 300 columns, and i want to choose selected columns and get this thing done. So I cant take df.column **

Comment: Well then just index the dataframe on a list of columns. So change all `df` with `df[my_list_of_columns]`

Comment: could you please edit the answer for the same so that It would be easier for everyone to visualize.

Comment: No. The answer answers the proposed question as it was initially. If I change my answer now it could mislead future visitors. Also please don't forget you can accept and upvote answers, thanks! @amit

Answer (score 1):

You could simply iterate on the columns in reverse order:

```
for col in reversed(df.columns):
    df.loc[df[col],'result'] = col
```

It gives:

```
       A      B      C result
0   True  False  False      A
1  False  False   True      C
2   True  False  False      A
3  False  False  False    NaN
```

Comment: **what if a and b both are true? what would happen in that case?**

Comment: @Amit: the first True column wins.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC `dot`

```
df.dot(df.columns)
0    A
1    C
2    A
3     
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Update pandas 1.5+ [`pd.from_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#from-dummies):

```
pd.from_dummies(df, default_category='na')
```

Output:

```
0   A
1   C
2   A
3  na
```

Therfore,

```
df['result'] = pd.from_dummies(df, default_category='na')
df
```

Output:

```
       A      B      C result
0   True  False  False      A
1  False  False   True      C
2   True  False  False      A
3  False  False  False     na
```